# Apache2 Error Log

Tags: apache, ubuntu, apache2, ubuntu-12.04

I am running Apache 2.2 with PHP5.3 running a PHP business app. Everything works fine from a business point of view, however I do get an error in my apache error.log

```
[Thu Nov 01 12:07:17 2012] [error] [client 10.200.8.37] File does not exist: /var/www/webroot/itassistant
[Thu Nov 01 12:07:17 2012] [error] [client 10.200.8.37] File does not exist: /var/www/webroot/xmldata
```

In my access.log the following is logged:

```
10.200.8.37 - - [01/Nov/2012:12:07:17 +0100] "GET /itassistant/ui/omaBaseFrame.htm HTTP/1.1" 404 490 "-" "Jakarta Commons-HttpClient/3.0.1"
10.200.8.37 - - [01/Nov/2012:12:07:17 +0100] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 348073 "-" "Jakarta Commons-HttpClient/3.0.1"
10.200.8.37 - - [01/Nov/2012:12:07:17 +0100] "GET /xmldata?item=All HTTP/1.1" 404 485 "-" "Jakarta Commons-HttpClient/3.0.1"
```

The PHP log gives no errors.

The PHP applications is the only application I am running and my application provider says that this isn't caused by the application.

I am running on an Ubuntu 12.04 server. Can anybody help me find the cause of these errors? How can I find out what is trying to call these non existing items and why

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have the same message in my access-logs, on al my web-servers. The message is logged daily, always at the same time. In our case HP-SIM (Systems Insight Manager monitoring tool) is causing these messages.